# Qual é a origem do apelido «tripeiro» dado aos portuenses?

Tags: etimologia, gentílicos

Todos sabemos que *tripeiro* designa um habitante ou natural da cidade do Porto. Alguns dicionários, como o Houaiss e o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/tripeiro), dizem que é pejorativo; outros, como o da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa ou o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tripeiro), não. Este assunto foi objeto desta [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/is-it-offensive-to-call-a-native-portuense-tripeiro).

Segundo [uma narrativa](http://joelcleto.no.comunidades.net/lenda-dos-tripeiros), portuenses adquiriram o apelido *tripeiro* por ficarem só com as tripas, depois de fornecerem a carne limpa à expedição que foi [conquistar Ceuta em 1415](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquista_de_Ceuta). Noutra versão, foi em 1384, quando uma pequena [frota partiu do Porto carregada de víveres para ir socorrer Lisboa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerco_de_Lisboa_(1384)) há uns meses cercada pelos castelhanos. Mas nenhum dos sites que contam estas narrativas apresenta qualquer evidência de *tripeiro* já ser usado nesses tempos remotos; alguns sites dizem abertamente que a associação do apelido *tripeiro* com aquelas expedições reais é mera lenda.

Portanto a minha pergunta é:

- Até onde se consegue remontar a designação *tripeiro* aplicada aos portuenses?
- Quando é que esta designação aparece pela primeira vez no registo escrito?
- E foram os próprios que assim se alcunharam? Ou foram outros, possivelmente pejorativamente?

Comment: Eu diria que tem a ver com "as tripas à moda do Porto".

Comment: @JorgeB. Também acho que terá de ter alguma coisa a ver com isso. Agora temos que saber qual é que apareceu primeiro. Poderia vir também dos vendedores de tripa.

Comment: O Porto prosperou com o comércio com as frotas de Cruzados a caminho da Terra Santa. Muito do que os Cruzados compravam era carne. Talvez ficassem os pobres com as entranhas.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Essa não sabia; só sabia a das expedições a Ceuta e de socorro a Lisboa. Mas temos primeiro é que descobrir quando é que *tripeiro* aparece no registo escrito com o significado de *portuense*.

Answer (score 2):

A origem do nome é efectivamente uma lenda.

**1. Até onde se consegue remontar a designação tripeiro aplicada aos portuenses?**

A designação de tripeiro é anterior à construção da frota para a conquista de Ceuta e teve a origem no cerco de Lisboa.

**2. Quando é que esta designação aparece pela primeira vez no registo escrito?**

Não sei a resposta.

**3. E foram os próprios que assim se alcunharam?**

A alcunha foi dada por outros.

**4. Ou foram outros, possivelmente pejorativamente?**

Actualmente dependendo da origem de quem a invoca será negativa ou positiva. Originalmente não sei qual terá sido a conotação.

Fonte: https://www.infopedia.pt/$lenda-dos-tripeiros (um dicionário da Porto Editora)

Comment: A pergunta é quando é que aparece por escrito o nome *tripeiro*: quero qualquer coisa como, "nesta publicação do ano tal os portuenses já aparecem com o apelido de *tripeiros*". Essa narrativa que tu reproduzes já vem apresentada na pergunta, e possivelmente não passa de uma lenda.

Comment: Agora dizes que a designação *tripeiro* vem do tempo do cerco de Lisboa de 1383. Mas a tua fonte diz que isso é uma lenda! E tu apresentas a lenda como se fosse história verídica. E mais uma vez, essa narrativa já está incluída na própria pergunta. O que é preciso são dados contretos sobre o uso do nome no passado.